# unifying const T& and T&& overloads

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

I have the following two function template overloads:

```
template<typename T>
optional<T> some(const T& x)
{
    return optional<T>(x);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value, optional<T> >::type
some(T&& x)
{
    return optional<T>(std::move(x));
}
```

My first attempt at unifying the overloads via perfect forwarding failed:

```
template<typename T>
optional<T> some(T&& x)
{
    return optional<T>(std::forward<T>(x));
}

error: forming pointer to reference type 'const std::basic_string<char>&'
```

As did my second attempt:

```
template<typename T>
optional<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> some(T&& x)
{
    return optional<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(x));
}

error: no matching function for call to
'std::basic_string<char>::basic_string(gpa::optional<const std::basic_string<char> >)'
```

Is there a clean way to unify the overloads, or should I just live with having them?

Comment: You should provide a definition of what `optional<>` is.

Comment: It's basically a toy clone of `boost::optional`.

Comment: ... And yet the question stands, can you provide the definition? I have the feeling that the issue is with the interface of `optional` (i.e. perfect forwarding is the solution for `some`, you might need to tweak it to fit `optional`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the best way to do this is to take the object by value and let the *caller* decide whether to copy or move it:

```
template<typename T>
optional<T> some(T x)
{
    return optional<T>(std::move(x));
}
```

If the caller calls it with a temporary or uses `std::move` on their value, then it's moved. Otherwise it's copied.

Yes, this does mean that you'll do one additional move (which, if movement is the same as copying, means doing two copies). If that's a significant performance problem for you, then you'll have to use the two overloads implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with your `optional`, but perhaps you need to add:

```
typename remove_const< ... >::type
```

around your `remove_reference` in two places.  (because your 1st overload of your 2-overload solution - which I assume is passing all of your tests - effectively does a `remove_const` when declaring `optional<T>`).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `remove_cv` just to be on the safe side?

Comment: <shrug> If that's what is desired.  The current 2-overload solution just rejects volatile-qualified lvalues.  It is difficult for me to tell what is desired without a complete code example.